# Tailwind css not getting included in project

Tags: css, tailwind-css, postcss

I am using tailwind post CSS in my HTML, but classes are not applying.
I have installed all packages have linked CSS too.

tailwindconfigjs file

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["*"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Is there anything to change?

Comment: Are you using any Frameworks or anything? Or just Plain HTML?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm using Tailwind CSS in vs code no other frameworks, the problem is tailwind CSS is not showing any effect on my page when I am using tailwind postcss

Comment: make sure you are following the docs guide.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: Thank you:)   Donno where i did mistake But after changing the config file as below it started working  ```const newLocal = module.exports = {
  content: ["*"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
``` If you know reason for this do comment

Answer (score 0):

In tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

2. Add Tailwind directives to your css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

3. Start Tailwind CLI build process by running

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

4. Add your compiled CSS file to the  and start using Tailwind’s utility classes to style your content.

```
<link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Refer https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation for more details